# How to find the number of sides of the shapes with image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find the number of edges on the figures below. I use Python and opencv. I could not calculate the number of edges. The number of edges in the figures is 4,7,5,8 respectively.

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(material_contourImage, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
epsilon = 0.03 * cv2.arcLength(contours[0], True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0], epsilon, True)
b = len(approx)
```

b is the number of edges.
but I am changing 0.03. While one is true, the other is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

[image: opencv]

[image]

Comment: why the first one is 4 edge? looksmore like 7 segments.  If you want to approximate like this, it will be very difficult to do using traditional CV algorithm.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Edit post thank you.

Comment: what is an "edge" in your opinion?

Comment: Edge is straight, not curve. But edge is counted on a large slope as in figure-1.

Comment: Any answer? :SS I think this problem cannot be solved.